# Chef not processing sed correctly

Tags: ruby, sed, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Whenever I write a recipe, Chef never seems to use sed correctly. I can generally work around it with some creative grep'ing, but not in this case. I'm just trying to extract the Distinguished Name from some cert files. Removing the backslash before the single quotes, this command executes just fine on the command line. Chef also doesn't throw any errors. The "not working" part comes in because the output that is stored in the "DN" variable is just the openssl command contents, as if the sed was never ran at all. I also ran this as straight Ruby code and it executed fine. It appears to be just Chef that is casuing the issue.

```
filesAndExpArray = splitArray.map! do |file|
  DN = shell_out("openssl x509 -noout -subject -in #{file} | sed \'s/^.*CN=//\'")
  DN = DN.stdout
  file + ";" + DN
end
```

Comment: Which version of chef ? Some logs could be helpful to get what's wrong there...

Comment: Try running `type sed` in your shell/Terminal and using the full path that you see rather than bare `sed` in your recipe. Also try a simpler `sed` command, such as `sed 's/./#/g'`.

Comment: Chef: 12.15.19 and which log?

Comment: Also tried full path to sed, as well as with simpler command, still failed (aka all . were not replaced with #)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names starting with a capital letter in Ruby are constants, that is probably related. Use `dn` instead. Also while you could do this, it's going to be easier and faster to do the regex in Ruby code instead as you don't need to sort out how to fix your quoting (you probably don't need those backslashes).

```
filesAndExpArray = splitArray.map do |file|
  cmd = shell_out("openssl x509 -noout -subject -in #{file}")
  dn = cmd.stdout[/^.*CN=(.*)$/, 1]
  file + ";" + dn
end
```

If you wanted to go even further you could ditch `shell_out` entirely:

```
filesAndExpArray = splitArray.map do |file|
  subject = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(IO.read(file)).subject
  cn = subject.to_a.find {|part| part.first == 'CN'}
  dn = cn && cn[1]
  file + ";" + dn
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your issue in a pry session:

```
[2] pry(main)> file = "server.crt"
=> "server.crt"
[11] pry(main)> require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'
=> true
[12] pry(main)> include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut
=> Object
[13] pry(main)> shell_out!("openssl x509 -noout -subject -in #{file} | sed \'s/^.*CN=//\'").stdout
=> "*.<CENSORED>.org\n"
```

You may have an issue with Ruby like @coderanger suggests because DN is a constant in Ruby, you should be seeing error messages like this then:

```
(pry):15: warning: already initialized constant DN
(pry):14: warning: previous definition of DN was here
```